# Remove colour from footnote reference inside footnote

Tags: hyperref, color, footnotes

Is there any way to keep the footnote reference colour inside the text, such as the magenta "7" here:

[image]

but make the colour black in the actual footnote, i.e. making the magenta "7" here black:

[image]

What I have thus far in the preamble is:

```
\usepackage[hidelinks, pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=magenta}
\renewcommand\thefootnote{\textcolor{magenta}{\arabic{footnote}}}
```

Thanks for any help here.

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: In a short example document I get what (I think) you want if I just leave out the `\renewcommand\thefootnote{\textcolor{magenta}{\arabic{footnote}}}`.

Comment: @moewe Yes -- that works :-/. Thanks a lot for your time!